# How can I loop through a nested list to store the values in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, nested-lists

Given a nested dictionary `neighborhood_data` and that the first item i.e `neighborhood_data[0]` displays

```
{'type': 'Feature',
 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon',
  'coordinates': [[[[28.073783, -26.343133],
     [28.071239, -26.351536],
     [28.068717, -26.350644],
     [28.06663, -26.351362],
     [28.065161, -26.352135],
     [28.064671, -26.35399]]]],
'properties': {'cartodb_id': 1,
  'subplace_c': 761001001,
  'province': 'Gauteng',
  'wardid': '74202012',
  'district_m': 'Sedibeng',
  'local_muni': 'Midvaal',
  'main_place': 'Alberton',
  'mp_class': 'Settlement',
  'sp_name': 'Brenkondown',
  'suburb_nam': 'Brenkondown',
  'metro': 'Johannesburg',
  'african': 330,
  'white': 24,
  'asian': 0,
  'coloured': 2,
  'other': 0,
  'totalpop': 356}}}
```

I then created an empty data frame `neighborhoods`

```
# define the dataframe columns
column_names = ['Province', 'District', 'Local_municipality','Main Place', 'Suburb','Metro','Latitude','Longitude'] 

# instantiate the dataframe
neighborhoods = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

However when I looped through `neighborhoods_data` to store the relevant data in the `neighborhoods` data frame I got the following error

```
for data in neighborhood_data:
    province = data['properties']['province']
    district = data['properties']['district_m']
    local_muni_name = suburb_name = data['properties']['local_muni'] 
    suburb_name = data['properties']['suburb_nam']
    metro = data['properties']['metro']
    
    suburb_latlon = data['geometry']['coordinates']
    subur_lat = suburb_latlon[[[[1]]]]
    suburb_lon = suburb_latlon[[[[0]]]]
    
    neighborhoods = neighborhoods.append({'Province': province,
                                          'District': district,
                                          'Local_municipality': local_muni_name,
                                          'Main place': main_place,
                                          'Suburb': suburb_name,
                                          'Metro': metro,
                                          'Latitude': suburb_lat,
                                          'Longitude': suburb_lon}, ignore_index=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a5dc74ed4207> in <module>
      7 
      8     suburb_latlon = data['geometry']['coordinates']
----> 9     subur_lat = suburb_latlon[[[[1]]]]
     10     suburb_lon = suburb_latlon[[[[0]]]]
     11 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

So how can I store the latitude and longitude coordinates in the columns 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' for the empty data frame?

Comment: suburb_latlon[0][0][0][1]

Comment: Your dictionary is malformed in the `coordinates` field, it misses some closing square brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary is malformed, it misses closing square brackets in the `coordinates` key, but let's assume that this is the correct dictionary:

```
{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[[28.073783, -26.343133],
     [28.071239, -26.351536],
     [28.068717, -26.350644],
     [28.06663, -26.351362],
     [28.065161, -26.352135],
     [28.064671, -26.35399]]]],
  'properties': {'african': 330,
   'asian': 0,
   'cartodb_id': 1,
   'coloured': 2,
   'district_m': 'Sedibeng',
   'local_muni': 'Midvaal',
   'main_place': 'Alberton',
   'metro': 'Johannesburg',
   'mp_class': 'Settlement',
   'other': 0,
   'province': 'Gauteng',
   'sp_name': 'Brenkondown',
   'subplace_c': 761001001,
   'suburb_nam': 'Brenkondown',
   'totalpop': 356,
   'wardid': '74202012',
   'white': 24},
  'type': 'MultiPolygon'},
 'type': 'Feature'}
```

Then, to access

```
suburb_latlon = data['geometry']['coordinates']
subur_lat = suburb_latlon[[[[1]]]] # <--- Indexing error here
suburb_lon = suburb_latlon[[[[0]]]] # <--- Indexing error here
```

We want to do the following (unpack through the extra list levels until we have our coordinate):

```
suburb_latlon = data['geometry']['coordinates']
subur_lat = suburb_latlon[0][0][0][1] # <--- Not sure what your logic is here, and why you would pick the first one, but I'll assume that given this indexing procedure you can customize this.
suburb_lon = suburb_latlon[0][0][0][0] # <--- Same here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick feedback. I have managed to fix the errors populate the neighborhoods data frame with the correct coordinates. It's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the format for your coordinates is incorrect. You currently have three square braces opening for it, but none closing for it:

```
'coordinates': [[[[28.073783, -26.343133]... [28.064671, -26.35399],
```

If you want to keep the current format, you need to make sure your data has the three missing square brackets at the end ']]]' or remove two at the start and format your coordinates as follows:

```
'coordinates' : [[28.073783, -26.343133], [28.071239, -26.351536]...]
```

You can then access using:

```
suburb_latlon = data['geometry']['coordinates']
subur_lat = suburb_latlon[[0][1]]
suburb_lon = suburb_latlon[[0][0]]
```

To access the first list item [28.073783, -26.343133] and then assign lat to the second element in that list, and lon to first item in that list.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Robert. I will actually try to change the format just  to see what happens. I forgot to include the 3 brackets at the end after I deleted the coordinates at the end.